# How to use UITextfield's text in multiple UITextfields?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, sdk

I'm using a UITextfield to input information. I have several UITextfields that need to equal the input UITextfield. I'm using this bit of code:

```
       tex34.text = tex33.text;
```

How do I expand the code to handle multiple textfields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no 'broadcast' idea that will allow you to set them all with one statement. You'll just have to have as many assignments as you have text fields. If you have a billion of them, you could write some Perl to output the code.

e.g.

```
tex34.text = text33.text;
tex35.text = text33.text;
tex36.text = text33.text;
tex37.text = text33.text;
```

If you're in a tight loop, you can save some property read invocations using a temporary string:

```
const NSString *text = tex33.text;
tex34.text = text;
tex35.text = text;
//etc
```

If you *really* have a lot of them (unlikely), you can build the text field variable names as NSStrings and use key-value-coding to update their text property:

```
const NSString *text = tex33.text;

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

for (int i = 34; i < 1653; i++) {
   const NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tex%d.text", i];
   [self setValue:text forKey:key];
   if (i % 100 == 0) [pool drain];
}

[pool release];
```

This approach will require that you have each `texXX` set up as a property...

Comment: Probably easier to use an IBOutletCollection.