# UILabel multi-set values

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I know this is going to sound like a trivial question but I have defined 50 labels in my *.h file

```
UILabel *tempLabel1;
UILabel *tempLabel2;
UILabel *tempLabel3;
...
UILabel *tempLabel50;
```

In my *.c file I want to set the value for each of those labels but I don't want to do it manually or write them out over and over again.

```
//Instead of doing this
tempLabel1.text = @"1";
tempLabel2.text = @"2";
...
tempLabel50.text = @"50";   


//I would like to do something like this
//I know this isn't correct syntax but want to know if something like
//this can be done?
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
{
    tempLabel[i].text = @"%d", i+1;
}
```

Comment: Sure. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9507909/1224741

Comment: @psoft ... I looked at it and sorry I didn't get it.

Comment: Which is the part you don't understand?

Comment: this syntax is definitely incorrect.

Comment: look at the third example in the answer psoft referred you to - it shows use of key value pairs to set the property names which enable's you to dynamically create the property names in your loop and set them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one way that comes to mind (not the cleanest but A way) is to do the following:

```
UILabel *tempLabels[50];
```

The problem you run into then is you can't use IB to connect them. Instead what you do is use the **tag** property in each of them (this means you need to set the tag for all 50 UILabels). To properly connect them you run this in viewDidLoad:

```
for (index = 1; index < 50; ++index)
{
    tempLabels[index] = (UILabel *) [self.view viewWithTag: index];
}
```

Bingo! Now anywhere in your code if you need to change the labels you can do the following:

```
for (index = 1; index < 50; ++index)
{
    tempLabels[index].text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Number %d", index];
}
```

It's kind of tedious setting the tags, but once you are done, you are done.

BTW, unlike the other solutions, you can use IB to create your labels.

Comment: Fixed a typo where I had "UIButton" instead of UILabel in the answer. Sorry if that confused anyone.

Answer (score 1):

this would be a good start for you, I guess.

```
NSMutableArray *_labels = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
    UILabel *_newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init]; // please, make the init method as you wish
    // ... any customization of the UILabel
    [_newLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
    [_newLabel setTag:i];
    [_labels addObject:_labels];
    [self.view addSubview:_newLabel];
}

// ... and then you can do the following

for (int i = 0; i < _labels.count; i++) {
    [((UILabel *)[_labels objectAtIndex:i]) setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the UILabels programmatically and hence have access to them - so you can set their text value as well.

You can add a UILabel like this:

```
    UILabel *theLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)]; //need to calculate the x,y coordinates in dependency of i
    theLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i];
    [self.view addSubview:theLabel]; // add it to your view
    myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // change the color
```

If you need access to the labels later as well, just add them to an NSArray that you keep.